# Wrap Flutter module in library to use it by other apps

Tags: flutter, module, wrapper, flutter-add-to-app

I want to wrap a Flutter module in a Android/iOS library and then use it in a host app. Like a 3 layers app:

1- Flutter module
2- Android / iOS library use Flutter module
3- Android / iOS app use library

The idea is distribute Android/iOS library for be used by others in theirs apps.

I spend a lot of time searching for documentation or guide but I don't find anything. Only use Flutter module directly in host app.

Any ideas or a doc I can read for orientation? If exist a sample will be ideal